# Tabbed Browser Error "Variable 'NewBrowser' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

Tags: browser, web

I have got the error about my Tabbed WebBrowser, I had watched a TUTORIAL from YouTube, I have VB 2008 but he has the 2010 version in which could be the cause.

This is the code below, I've highlighted the item that has caused this.

```
Dim NewBrowser As CustomBrowser
Dim NewTab As New TabPage
NewBrowser.Tag = NewTab
NewTab.Tag = ***NewBrowser***
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
NewTab.Controls.Add(NewTab)
NewBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
NewBrowser.Navigate(URL)
```

I am needing a specific answer for this, as I looked everywhere else on StackOVERFLOW and the answers were irrelevant.

Thank You